# blonde haired and blue eyed people in Bharata varsha in earlier yugas

Tags: culture, human

I am interested in knowing whether people in Bharata varsha in earlier yugas had blonde hair and blue eyes(the combination). Or is that combination foreign to Bharat varsha ?

Usually these are attributed to colder climates and northern latitudes [Northern European](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blond). But presuming Bharat was a lot cooler in earlier yugas was this combination found in ancient Bharata varsha ?

I have read the word  [Harikesha](http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?beginning=0%20&tinput=%20harikeza&trans=Translate) in many texts of descriptions of deities but I am unsure whether ordinary humans had these characteristics.

To me the first encounter of a blonde haired/blue eyed person would have happened when Alexander's armies entered Northern India but are any other descriptions of such encounters in earlier yugas?

Comment: @iammilind - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madra_Kingdom - can you say where it says Madra is in Russia ? Unless Russian borders extended to Afghanistan....

Comment: I don't remember where I read. It might be a wrong information as well probably based on [Shalya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shalya_(urban-type_settlement)) region in Russia. Anyways, it's not part of India and that's out of scope for your question. Hence deleting my comment above. However there is some linking between [Medes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medes) tribe and [Madra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madra) kingdom. But all are out of scope of current Indian subcontinent.

Comment: @iammilind - just like Narada mountain in Urals ?

Comment: The word "Hindu" did not exist in earlier yugas.If you are asking whether some Sanatana Dhrama followers did have blonde hair in earlier yugas then the answer will be yes.Because the only Dhrama that prevailed in the world in all the earlier yugas is the true Dhrama i.e the Sanatana Dharma.

Comment: @Rickross - go ahead and write it up if you feel confident about it. But I will only upvote and accept if you can add a single source. In my question I provided a word from scriptures. So that is the least I can accept in an answer.

Comment: @moonstar2001 - but the question is about blonde ? I would appreciate if the discussion were kept to that point.

Comment: @moonstar2001 - All people are Hindu I accept. Can you show some of them had blonde hair ?

Comment: I don't know about blonde hair but many red haired people are described in Bhagavatam. The only blonde I know of is Lord Shiva.

Comment: Interesting question. Harikesha also finds mention in lalitha trishati. A related article http://www.advaita-vedanta.org/archives/advaita-l/1998-August/009296.html

Comment: @Surya - can you go ahead and write it up ? I would be happy to upvote it.

Comment: @gansub I will. Turns out there are three more blondes Kapila, Hiranyakashipu and Hiranyaksha.

Comment: @Surya - well done ! I look forward to upvoting your answer ! I am truly grateful for your research